# facebook graph API Unlike of feed not working

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, feed

I am not able to like a feed by a friend of the user. The unlike works if the feed has been posted by the session user. I am using the graph api endpoint /feed-id/likes. Also using the same endpoint i am able to like the feed, facing problems only for unlike. Getting the following response:
{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 200
}
}
The februrary breaking changes announced that only the call to [user_id]/feed where user-id is different from session user will fail.
Then why am I facing problems while trying to perform a DELETE on feed-id/likes, that too when a POST on feed-id/likes seems to work fine?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and solved in this way:

XXXX_YYYY is your feed-id, you can like it calling feed-id/likes using Method.POST, but for unlike you must use YYYY/likes using Method.DELETE.

PS: be sure that in your permissions you have "publish_stream".

Comment: Candy is right. Don't work. Try with story "... added a new photo"

Answer (score -1):

I get

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter url is required",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
```

when calling `YYYY/likes` using Method `DELETE`.